# Cordova | Sending videos to mobile phone

Tags: javascript, cordova, video

I'm looking for a way to transfer video files to a client's mobile **without streaming**. The reason is (client's request) to eliminate the cost of such a server due to an expected all-at-once high traffic.

So I have looked on base64 encoding, below is the time it takes to get the 19mb file (one with 100mb internet connection, second with a 3G connection). This could make the waiting painful, especially on 3G connection. [image: base64 video encode timing]

I have also considered using byte array to significantly reduce the file size, but it's hard passing it via JSON with all the escaping backslashes...

Finally, I have looked on another possible solution, and that is to **transfer** a video directly to the client's phone while the app is closed (pushing a notification when the file has uploaded in the client's phone), but that is probably one of Cordova's limitation (as far as i'm aware).

I'm searching a solution for this for weeks now, therefore I have placed a bounty on it, since I believe it's a question worth answering. Somebody someday will thank us for it. :) I'll be the first.

Much thanks, and happy coding.

Comment: I'm having problems understanding the intention of your question - why exactly can't the video file be embedded as straightforward HTML5 media? Using base64 you'll face an 30% increased data size.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i'm aware of that but the thing is the server is weak and the client doesn't want to host the videos, so the idea is to send it to the client and he will play it from his phone... So far our idea is to limit the file size to 5mb and use base64 to send the video, i'm just looking for a better solution than this...

Comment: I have modifying the question to be more specific and understandable

Answer (score 2):

## Hosting vs app serving

First of all you need to understand that no matter where the file is coming from - a file server (streaming) or application server (base64 encoded string), the hosting costs are going to be the similar (well, a file hosting server should be more effecient than anything you write, but that's a minor difference). You still need to store the file somewhere and you still need to send it over the network. The difference is only that in one case Apache/IIS/whatever server you use is handling all the complex stuff and in the second case you are going to be trying to recreate it all yourself.

## Streaming vs Non-Streaming

When you serve a file (be it yourself, or through a file server) you can either allow it to be retrieved in chunks (streamed) or only as a huge big file. In the first case - streaming - if the user stops watching halfway through the video you will only need the server capacity to serve like 60 or 70% of the file. In the second case - non-streaming - you need to have the user first wait for the file to be retrieved in it's *entirety* and on top of that it will always cost you 100% power.

## Precaching files

That's not to say nothing can be optimized. For example, if you are distributing a single file every week on saturday 6 pm, yet already know a full week before hand what that file is you could theoretically encrypt the file and serve it in the background distributed over the course of the entire week. And yes, you could even do that whilst building a Cordova application (though it will be a bit harder and you might end up writing your own plugin). Still though, that situation is incredibly rare and is definitely not worth the development time except in rare cases (e.g. it's often done with game files, but that's tens of GBs of data downloaded tens of thousands of times).

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I agree that streaming would be the better option in many ways, I wish my client could be convinced as I am about it. Precaching is off the record but it's a decent idea. 
I guess there's no real answer to it yet so I will give you the bounty in case no one comes with a magical solution in the next few days. :)

Comment: @Shay Well, the thing you will need to make clear to the client is that it's going to cost him more this way - both for hosting and development - , perform less well and provide him - or the user - no benefit whatsoever. And just to be clear, the precaching was in response to the wish to send a video file whilst the app was closed.

Comment: Yes I thought it was just for the idea, good idea nonetheless. :) I have tried to explain this to the client many times, I guess you learn best from your hardest mistakes hehe!

Comment: Thanks again for trying to help, as now we are getting close to testing I hope they will see how slow their servers are and decide to upgrade the server to allow streaming, or give up the video feature due to its costs :)